# Flash/Actionscript a substitute for css and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, flash

I have reasonable experience with PHP, CSS, and javascript/jquery/ajax. I'm taking my first steps learning Flex/Flash/Actionscript and it's already striking me that using flash/SWF could solve many of my problems. For example:

- I won't have to worry much about javascript availability e.g. handling the form submit twice like I do now, once for js available and one for js not available.
- There's also a CSS advantage: looks like things are very easy to style and drop in their correct exact spot in flash than it is with CSS (I hate CSS because I'm not that great at it and it usually gives me  a headache).

I know that all-flash websites are very very bad, so I'm not planning to use Flash for everything, **maybe for things that are not important like menus, registration forms, something that displays data that doesn't need to be indexed.** For those who are like me (not flash loyalists), **what parts of your webapp do you prefer to use flash for and think it does it better or in less time or without headache** than CSS/javascript/ajax on a PHP backend? Is my thinking correct to begin with?

Comment: You write double code now for 'with javascript' and for 'without' ... so you'll only have to do the same for 'with flash' and 'without'. 

You're right in terms of Flash solving those problems, of course, but you're going very much against the tide of opinion and practice in web development. Most people are working on the opposite transition -- doing things in Javascript and CSS and modern browsers that were only possible in Flash five years ago.

Comment: @Ambrose, do you (or someone who reads this) know some stats  for javascript support vs. flash support. I thought (correct me if I'm wrong) that flash was supported more widely than js.

Comment: I think Dan is correct about support stats: thanks to youtube and other streaming sites, flash is now everywhere. But again, text formatting with flash is a mess to say the least - css for the win when it comes to formatting text.

Comment: JavaScript is on more cell phones than Flash is.

Answer (score 2):

I personally try to use Flash only when another existing technology cannot handle it well. That normally involves advanced animation, and video embedding. Everything else I do with HTML/CSS + Javascript (with jQuery as needed) and backend tech. While it is true Flash "fixes" some of the problems you listed, I don't think you want to move this direction, for a few reasons:

1. As @Ambrose mentioned, you will be in a very small pond moving the opposite direction of most developers. Not sure how much support you will find. **EDIT:** Just to be clear. I realize there is a huge Flash developer community. I am specifically speaking of others "like you" that are *not* moving from HTML/CSS to Flash for the reasons you provided.
2. Mobile web use is rapidly increasing due to both the iPhone and Android platforms... Neither currently support Flash. (**EDIT** See [this article](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/admob_reports_on_mobile_webs_explosive_growth.php) for Smartphone browser stats)
3. Flash content cannot be easily repurposed for web, print, mobile in the same way as traditional technologies (CSS/HTML).
4. I find HTML/CSS + Javascript far more forgiving and easy to learn than Flash... but thats just me :)

Comment: 1. ? There is a strong, vibrant Flash Platform developer community. 2. only sorta true. 3. Depends on how you code it, I reuse all the time 4. markup, markup, loose language vs single proper OOP language. You sure it isn't because you know it already?

Comment: That said, I think all Flash websites are awful and you should add AS3/Flash to your toolkit and understand the HTML/CSS/JS as well.

Comment: @Joel, I realized my first reason was unclear. I have edited my response to reveal what I meant originally. 2. Is very true not "only sorta true" (added link to answer) 3. My point was it is not repurposed _in the same way_ as HTML/CSS: I can keep the same HTML and use simply different CSS (or different rules within a stylesheet) to render for a mobile browser instead. 4. I guess you didn't pick up on the "but thats just me" part of that answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

As you dive more into Flash, you will learn that text formatting within Flash is far from being perfect. Flash supports only a [very limited subset of HTML tags](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText). And very soon, you are gonna miss your good old HTML CSS, no matter how much headache it gives you now.

As others mentioned, use Flash for what it is meant for - delivering fantastic animations, streaming media (and Web 2.0 kinda menus, if you want).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a terrible idea.

When I run into a Flash website, it never feels quite "right." It looks and acts slightly different than the "normal" web. Flash is great for games and advertisements and providing media in old browsers. It is not an HTML/CSS/JS replacement.

What do you plan to do for visually impaired users who use screen readers?

I run away from Flash-based websites as quickly as I can. They often have artificial delays to show off their animations, making the page less interactive. If I sense that you are slumming amongst these tedious marketing-driven pages, I'll run away from your page, too.

That's not to say I dislike Flash. I like it. It's a great cross-platform gaming and audiovisual platform. I expect HTML to decrease its usage on the web, though. Eventually.